# If I have a visa, do I still need an ESTA?

Tags: usa, paperwork, esta, b1-b2-visas, uk-citizens

I am British with a B1/B2 visa for USA.  Do I still need an ESTA?

Comment: Just a side-remark: At least a few years ago, some airlines would not allow online check-in for flights to the US unless you were a US national *or* had a valid ESTA. So when traveling on a visa and you did not happen to have an ESTA as well, you would need to check-in at the airport instead.

Comment: You might still need to fill in some gov website. Check your visa to see if it says "enroll on ..." It is similar to esta but for visa owners

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. Here's what the US government has to say on the question (see this answer's edit history for the version that was available when the question was asked):

> **What if a traveler has a current, valid visa?**
>
> Individuals who possess a valid visa will still be able to travel to the United States on that visa for the purpose for which it was issued. Individuals traveling on valid visas are not required to apply for an ESTA authorization.
>
> **I have a B1/B2 visa. Do I need to apply for an ESTA?**
>
> If you already have a B1/B2 or any other valid visa and you are traveling for the purpose in which it was issued, you do not need to apply for an ESTA authorization.

Source: [Frequently asked questions](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel).

Comment: Excellent! In particular, thank you for the official reference.

Comment: Link down......

Comment: @Pacerier thanks.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

No, you do not need to apply for ESTA as your visa supersedes VWP eligible travel.

Answer (score 1):

ESTA is for travel under the VWP, the visa-free arragements applicable to Brits. As such, as you're not travelling under the VWP, you don't need an ESTA.